# VB .Net Can i manage all events from inside a groupbox in an efficient way?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, groupbox

I have a groupbox containing a lot of Checkboxes - only Checkboxes.

Is there a simple/fast way to handle the same event coming from different controls?

I know I can write a single sub and let it handle all the Events, but it's really time-consuming to write.

Using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: I would love to see this! anyway, how about creating a method called *DoSomething()* and for every *SelectedIndexChanged* event, just call *DoSomething();*???

Comment: I guess it would work, but it's just as time consuming as the other option :)

Comment: don't forget, you can have the designer view on half the screen and half the screen code. Double clicking on one, pasting the *DoSomething()* method on the other half. It's as fast as it's gonna get i'm afraid :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your time concern is about writing and managing a large `Handles` clause, you can simply loop through the `GroupBox`'s `Controls` collection upon construction of your `UserControl`/`Form` and wire up each event on each `CheckBox`, like so:

```
Imports System.Linq

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    For Each chkBox As CheckBox In yourGroupBoxVariable.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
        AddHandler chkBox.CheckStateChanged, AddressOf YourCheckStateChangedHandlerMethod
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub YourCheckStateChangedHandlerMethod(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Your handler code for the checkboxes
End Sub
```

This leverages LINQ's [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) Enumerable extension to filter down all child controls of the `GroupBox` to those of type `CheckBox`.

Comment: I don't know why someone would down vote this answer, but it seems very useful when handling events. Upvoted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to create a custom `GroupBox`, i.e. deriving from `GroupBox` and exposing the event yourself:

```
Public Class CheckboxGroup
  Inherits GroupBox

  Public Event CheckboxChanged(source As CheckBox, e As EventArgs)

  Protected Overrides Sub OnControlAdded(e As ControlEventArgs)
    ' this method is called everytime a checkbox is added
    If TypeOf e.Control Is CheckBox Then
      Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(e.Control, CheckBox)
      AddHandler chk.CheckedChanged, AddressOf AllCheckedChange
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub AllCheckedChange(source As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If TypeOf source Is CheckBox Then
      Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(source, CheckBox)
      RaiseEvent CheckboxChanged(chk, e)
    End If
  End Sub

End Class
```

You can then attach to the event in the `Form` like:

```
  Private Sub CheckboxChanged(source As CheckBox, e As EventArgs) Handles gb.CheckboxChanged
    MsgBox(source.Text & " to " & source.Checked)
  End Sub
```

Advantage: you can never miss to add an event handler to a `CheckBox`, even if it is created dynamically.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you!
[Avanek](http://stackoverflow.com/users/357625/avanek)'s answer isbetter suited for the situation I'm in, but this IS indeed very useful!